# Form Filling setting value as Watermark

Tags: c#

i m tring to fill a small form on Third party website through C# the problem is the my C# code will the text box value but the page is treating that value as watermark or Empty Textbox Message and when i try to submit that form its say textboxes are empty....

```
HtmlDocument document = webBrowser1.Document;
HtmlElement inputValue = document.GetElementById("TextBoxName");
inputValue.SetAttribute("value", "334511");
```

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Use inputValue.InnerText instead.

Answer (score 0):

use this code you will get the textbox value in inputValue variable...

```
 HtmlElement inputValue = document.GetElementById("TextBoxName").value;
 alert(inputValue);
```